# How to call a method on a generic type from inside the generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class TableStorageItem
{
    public TableStorageItem() { }
}
```

```
public abstract class TableStorage<T> where T : TableStorageItem, new()
{
    public async Task CheckInitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

```
public class TableStorageCleanerTask<T, U>
    where T : TableStorage<U>
    where U : TableStorageItem, new()
{
    public TableStorageCleanerTask() { }

    public async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        await T.CheckInitializeAsync(cancellationToken)
    }
}
```

I would like to call `CheckInitializeAsync` from inside `InitializeAsync` but I have this CS0704 compiler error:

> Cannot do non-virtual member in T because it is a type parameter.

I am sure that there is a way to do this but I can't figure it out.

Comment: `CheckInitializeAsync` is not static. Why did you expect `T.CheckInitializeAsync(cancellationToken)` to work?

Comment: You've misquoted the error text.  It should have the word **lookup** in it: `Cannot do non-virtual member lookup in 'T' because it is a type parameter`  It's best to copy and paste error text when asking a question.

Comment: I suspect the downvotes come from the fact that the error text and line number exactly explain the problem.  And a quick search on the internet would point to the solution.  One valid reason for downvoting is "does not show any research effort".

Comment: @Wyck I did a research of course, including Bing Copilot because it is amazing at finding answers. But you're right I may have not copy/paste the error text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to call instance method like static method. You have to declare your function as following that accepts a TableStorage instance or you may create a new instance then call CheckInitializeAsync() function in InitializeAsync():

```
public class TableStorageCleanerTask<T, U>
where T : TableStorage<U>
where U : TableStorageItem, new()
{
    public TableStorageCleanerTask() { }

    public async Task InitializeAsync(T storage, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        await storage.CheckInitializeAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per @Sweeper's comment, the `CheckInitializeAsync` method is not static, so cannot be called against the class; only against an object instantiated from that class.

```cs
public class TableStorageCleanerTask<T, U>
    where T : TableStorage<U>
    where U : TableStorageItem, new()
{
    private T tableStorage;
    public TableStorageCleanerTask(T tableStorage)
    {
        this.tableStorage = tableStorage;
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        await tableStorage.CheckInitializeAsync(cancellationToken)
    }
}
```